# Haskell list confusion

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to translate a radix sort algorithm from Java to Haskell, and I'm *really* new to Haskell. I've been reading tutorials, but they are so lengthy and I'm trying to get my hands dirty now.

I'll be passing a list of lists to the sort algorithm, and my questions are:

- How would I traverse all elements in a list?
- How would I access a particular element within a list?

So for instance, I'd need to traverse over every list I have, and access particular elements by index (?) in that particular list. How!?

Comment: Lists are not arrays.  For example, accessing the nth element of a list costs `O(n)`, instead of O(1).  If you started with an array in Java then I suggest you use a [Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) or [Array](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array) in Haskell, not a list.  OTOH, if this really is homework then the instructor probably does want you using lists.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I will keep away from lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged your question as homework, I'm going to give you a few pointers but no solution.  A Haskell book that seems to be particularly beginner friendly is ["Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) (LYAH).  You can buy it or read it online for free.

- Traversing a list requires recursion.  See [Chapter 5](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) of LYAH.
- For accessing a list element by index you can use the `!!` operator.  Note, though, that if you give it an invalid index you get an error.  Indexing starts at 0.  For a few more standard utility functions on lists, see [Chapter 2](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists) of LYAH.

Comment: Also, these are essentially linked lists, so "indexing" a list actually takes time linear in the index. It's usually a terrible idea and really something that should be more heavily discouraged (as should use of `head` and `tail`, which I regard as bugs until proven otherwise).